# Add grid to custom adminhtml page

Tags: admin, grid, grid-serlization

I am currently following a tutorial series which teaches you how to add pages and features within the admin section of your site. The current part I am on shows how to add a grid onto the page.

My problem is that when I get to the page it shows the magento header and footer found in the admin section but the content area is blank. In that blank area I expected to see a grid. I am not getting any error messages (they are on). I have my cache disabled. I am struggling through this tutorial as there are not many descriptions as to what the code is doing and when I should be testing code so I am trying to review code which is being extended and often getting confused.

From what I understand the code that should display the grid is the following

```
class Excellence_Employee_Adminhtml_EmployeeController
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Excellence/Employee/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
....
  <menu>
    <employee module="employee">
        <title>Employee</title>
        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
        <children>
            <items module="employee"><!--adds menu item-->
                <title>Manage Employees</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/employee</action><!--Link-->
            </items>
```

design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/employee.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <employee_adminhtml_employee_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="employee/adminhtml_employee" name="employee" />
    </reference>
  </employee_adminhtml_employee_index>
</layout>
```

.

```
class Excellence_Employee_Block_Adminhtml_Employee
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_employee';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'employee';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('employee')->__('Employee Manager');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('employee')->__('Add Employee');

    $this->_addButton('button1', array(
       'label'      => Mage::helper('employee')->__('Button Label1'),
       'onclick'    => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('*/*/button1') . '\')',
       'class'      => 'add' 
    ));

    $this->_addButton('button2', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('employee')->__('Button Label2'),
        'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('*/*/button2') . '\')',
        'class'     => 'remove'
    ));

    parent::_construct();
}
}
```

1 - am I looking at the correct blocks of code?

2a - if not where should I look?

2b - if so, why isn't the grid showing up?

If it helps the two tutorials that I have been following are [Tut1](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs#more-657) and [Tut2](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/admin-part2-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs#more-657). At the end of Tut1 is the time the author says the grid should be displayed and tut2 adds to that grid, I have added tut2 just incase there is some relevant information in there

Comment: It looks like you are missing the Excellence_Employee_Block_Adminhtml_Employee_Grid (as described in Tut1), this is the place where the grid is configured.

Comment: Apologies for missing that out I do have it, but never posted it as I though that added items to the grid. There are eight seperate functions within that file, which one should be creating the block?

Comment: `_prepareCollection()` & `_prepareColumns()`. The container you've created will handle everything else.

Comment: @benmarks Thankyou for your response. I have looked and cant see what I have wrong in them, so I added a var_dump and die statement to the script to see what I was getting. It seems they are not being used when the page is being generated. I've just started to use x-debug to try and step through my scripts. Is it possible to use this on the admin area of Magento as I cant work out how it would be done due to the random generate number in the address bar. Could you advise how I am best to review which parts of my script are being used?

Comment: In which Xpath is your controller directory configured? `admin/routers/adminhtml/modules/[your node]` or `admin/routers/[your node]`? It will affect the layout update handle you are using.

Comment: I have used adminhtml.xml and in that it goes config/menu/mymodule/children/items/action and in the action I have placed my adminhtml/employee link.

Comment: Check what this function resolves the grid block to:

'protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }'

you are mostly interested in this bit : $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid'

does that exactly match the class name of your grid file, as well as the path (structure)? Is the file in the right place (grid.php)

Comment: to continue: If you think that is all good, in the constructor of your grid.php file, do a die (or log or breakpoint) - this will show you if the grid.php class has actually been instantiated/loaded. If so, then look in that class for any issues (like the columns created/collection built etc)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like potentially your admin xml layout fragment isn't getting picked up.  In your module config.xml file do you have:

```
<config>
....
   <adminhtml>
     <layout>
       <updates>
         <employee>
           <file>employee.xml</file>
         </employee>
       </updates>
     </layout>
   </adminhtml>
...
</config>
```